# get contextMenu title in onclick listener chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get the title of the contextMenu item clicked in chrome extension.

I can get the menuItemId but not the title.

```
function getClickHandler() {
  return function(info, tab) {
    console.warn(info.menuItemId)
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no function in the API mapping the item ID to other properties.

You'll need to maintain your own mapping as you're adding menu items if you need it.